# PostgreSQL - How call a procedure with a varchar parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I am trying to create a SP in Postgresql 12:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE trans_buy(
        _name_client varchar(25),
        _id_product smallint,
        _mount smallint
    )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS
    $$

    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO invoices (cliente) VALUES(_name_client);
        INSERT INTO invoices_details (id_invoice, id_product, mount) VALUES (1, _id_product, _mount, 100);
    END
    $$
```

But when I try to call this sp like so:

```
CALL trans_buy('james', 3, 10)
```

I receive this error message:

> doesnt exists the stored procedure << trans_buy(unknown, integer, integer) >>
>
> HINT: No procedure matches the name and types of arguments. It may be necessary to add explicit type conversion.

Comment: Which error do you get exactly?

Comment: explicit conversion error with the first param when i call the sp

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire, exact error message.

Comment: done, please checkout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need to explicitly cast the integer values to `smallint`s:

```
call trans_buy('james', 3::smallint, 10::smallint);
```

I assume that the target columns in `invoice_details` are `smallint` as well. An alternative is to have the procedure accept `int`s, and cast at `insert` time:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE trans_buy(
    _name_client varchar(25),
    _id_product int,
    _mount int
) LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO invoices (cliente) VALUES(_name_client);
    INSERT INTO invoices_details (id_invoice, id_product, mount) VALUES (1, _id_product::smallint, _mount::smallint);
END
$$
```

Note that your second insert had 4 values for 3 columns. I (attempted to) adjust that.

---

One should also highlight that you don't really need a subquery do this in Postgres. You can run multiple DML operations in a single query, using common-table-expressions:

```
with 
    -- CTE: query parameters
    params(cliente, id_product, mount) as (values ('james', 3, 10)),
    
    -- CTE: insert to invoices
    inv as (insert into invoices (cliente) select cliente from params)

-- insert to invoice details
insert into invoice_details (id_invoice, id_product, mount) 
select 1, id_product, mount from params
```