# ADO.NET : how to run sql query with parameters?

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, ado.net

version is PostgreSQL 14.2
I have perfect sql query:

```
select  
        details ->> 'id' as vr_id, 
        details ->> 'lastname' as lastname, 
        details ->> 'birthdate' as birthday, 
        jsonb_path_query_first(details, 
                              '$.contacts.phoneList[*] ? (@.fullNumber == "0671234567" && @.verifyStateId == 1)'
                             ) ->> 'businessId' as businessId,
        jsonb_path_query_first(details, 
                              '$.contacts.phoneList[*] ? (@.fullNumber == "0671234567" && @.verifyStateId == 1)'
                             ) ->> 'fullNumber' as fullnumber
from public.information
where details @? '$.contacts.phoneList[*] ? (@.fullNumber == "0671234567" && @.verifyStateId == 1)';
```

I need use in this SQL the parameters for phone number and stateId.

vPhone varchar := '0671234567';     --  fullNumber

vStateId int := 1;                  --  verifyStateId

something like that

```
select  
        details ->> 'id' as vr_id, 
        details ->> 'lastname' as lastname, 
        details ->> 'birthdate' as birthday, 
        jsonb_path_query_first(details, 
                              '$.contacts.phoneList[*] ? (@.fullNumber == "vPhone" && @.verifyStateId == vStateId)'
                             ) ->> 'businessId' as businessId,
        jsonb_path_query_first(details, 
                              '$.contacts.phoneList[*] ? (@.fullNumber == "vPhone" && @.verifyStateId == vStateId)'
                             ) ->> 'fullNumber' as fullnumber
from public.information
where details @? '$.contacts.phoneList[*] ? (@.fullNumber == "vPhone" && @.verifyStateId == vStateId)';
```

I plan use this sql as procedure for .Net Core API.

How I can to give these parameters to sql-query?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037107/postgresql-how-call-a-procedure-with-a-varchar-parameter

Comment: Try this Nuget library to simplify Ado.net code  : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ado.Entity